# How to catch specified error "[Errno 28] No space left on device" in Python

Tags: python

Here is a small part of my Python code:

```
except Exception1:
    logger.error("Exception 1. Exit.")
    sys.exit(-1)
except Exception 2, e:
    logger.error("Exception 2: {e}".format(e=e.message))
```

Sometimes I get an error:

```
INFO - 2019-01-28 16:44:49,399 - data_loader - ERROR - Exception 2: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

The problem is that program returns 0 code and I cannot see there was an error.

I found two solutions.

1:

```
except Exception1:
    logger.error("Exception 1. Exit.")
    sys.exit(-1)
except Exception 2, e:
    logger.error("Exception 2: {e}".format(e=e.message))
    raise
```

2:

```
except Exception1:
    logger.error("Exception 1. Exit.")
    sys.exit(-1)
except Exception 2, e:
    logger.error("Exception 2: {e}".format(e=e.message))
except [ExceptionCode]:
    raise("No space left on device")
```

My question is - how I can catch "no space left on device" in Pyhton? Is there any error code which I can use?

Comment: I believe the 'No space left' exception is either an IOError or an OSError - can't you just capture that (e.g. `except IOError`:)?

Answer (score 3):

```
import errno

try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    if e.errno == errno.ENOSPC:
        # no space left
        # handle it here
```

Comment: Only OSError has the `errno` attribute. Also don't forget to `raise` if you don't want to handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a valid exception then you get the name of exception like below. Once you have the name then you can handle that exception gracefully

```
try:
    #do something
except Exception as exception:
    print(exception.__class__.__name__)
```